# Error compiling kernel module with two source files

Tags: c, linux, makefile, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I am trying to compile a kernel module that has two .c files. My Makefile is the following

```
module-y: dummy.o library.o  
obj-m += module.o

default:
    make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=$(PWD) modules
```

When I run this I get

```
cc    -c -o dummy.o dummy.c
dummy.c:3:24: fatal error: linux/init.h: No such file or directory
```

It seems the Makefile doesn't know where to find the headers now.

I have tried using CFLAGS to add include directories, but there are so many of them that it becomes tedious and hard to do (haven't managed to make it work).

I would like to generate these two .o files using the include directories that are (magically) used when using a single .c file. Everything works fine in that case.

**How to fix the include directories when using two source files?**

Comment: Don't you need to compile with `-I./init` or such?

Comment: I haven't seen any example out there using that. At least for the single source case it is definitely not required.

Comment: this page: `https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt` is the official documentation on `kbuild`.  Suggest following the examples there for building an external module for the kernel.   Especially notice the use of `:=` and similar macro definition types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote the Makefile like the following, and it worked:

```
ifneq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)
# kbuild part of makefile
obj-m  := module.o
module-y := library.o dummy.o

else
# normal makefile
KDIR ?= /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build

default:
        $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$$PWD modules
endif
```